# Removal of google-api-v4 tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

Sadly, I am not allowed to delete the [google-api-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api-v4) tag but could someone add it as a synonym on [google-sheets-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-api), or [google-analytics-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics-api) please.

[image: tag synonym page screenshot]

I have retagged all current questions to use the proper tag. This tag just causes confusion.

Comment: I think it would be better to edit all questions to use the appropriate tags (not all are about Sheets - there are some analytics one) and then burninate the tag. I don't think it's helpful for the tag to exist at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet not a problem i can do that.  But i would like the tag deleted or synonymed to something.

Comment: If you do this fast enough, you will achieve the same effect. BTW, only users with at least 3k reputation can create tags, and there's a prompt asking them if they are sure of it.

Comment: @JonSkeet Done all Google-api-v4 have been created to either google-analyitcs-api or google-sheets-api respective to their relation to which api.

Comment: @Braiam will retaging all of them cause the tag to go away so that nothing gets tagged with this in the future?

Comment: @DaImTo - if no one uses the tag in 24 hours since the removal from all questions, yes. Regarding your original request, I don't think it is worth to keep API v4 around as a synonym of Sheets API. There is no guarantee that v4 won't be reused for something else and there can't be v4s of other APIs.

Comment: ^ this is basically about usage: if there is a tag referencing API v4, regardless of how the API is called (Sheets API v4 in our case), you bet users will start slapping it everywhere where one of Google APIs is versioned as 4. Better not to keep it around at all

Comment: I have retagged all the questions,  to remove it.   Lets hope it goes poof.

Comment: @DaImTo thumbs up. Will keep an eye on it for the next day in case it shows up